# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80080005)

Tags: c#, .net, com, powerpoint, office-automation

I am getting the error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80080005): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {91493441-5A91-11CF-8700-00AA0060263B} failed due to the following error: 80080005.

for line `PowerPoint.Application PowerPoint_App = new PowerPoint.Application();`

for this block of code here:

```
using (new Impersonator(Installs.Current.PPTUser, null, Installs.Current.PPTPassword))
{
    PowerPoint.Application PowerPoint_App = new PowerPoint.Application();
    PowerPoint.Presentation presentation = null;
    try
    {
        PowerPoint_App.Visible = MsoTriState.msoTrue;
        presentation = PowerPoint_App.Presentations.Open(
            strPptFilePath, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
            Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
            Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue);

        for (int i = 0; i < presentation.Slides.Count; i++)
        {
            readSlides(presentation, i);
        }
        presentation.Close();
        PowerPoint_App.Quit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        strSuccess = ex.ToString();
        MindMatrix.Libraries.Entities.ExceptionMessage.HandleException(ex, null);
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(presentation);
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(PowerPoint_App);
    }
}
```

whenever I run the code for the first time, it works perfectly, but then it creates process for PowerPoint (which can be seen in Task Manager). I have used `PowerPoint_App.Quit();` to quit the already open process, but it's not working and throwing me error. I go to Task Manager and end process from there and then it's ready to work for one more time.

Am I doing something wrong while quitting the process from code or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Is the powerpoint UI showing an error at the same time? Powerpoint COM server can fail quite easily if stressed heavily (in a loop for example).

Comment: I am not opening ppt ui.i am using images and text objects from ppt slides.They are further used in editor..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All right,that's how it went. i referred all the possible solution i can. from killing,quitting ,closing,Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject,GC Collect and WaitForPendingFinalizers. But nothing worked for me. so i found out the running process and killed it through code. And bamn everything works the way i expected.

**Code:**

```
  Process[] pros = Process.GetProcesses();
    for (int i = 0; i < pros.Count(); i++)
         {
           if (pros[i].ProcessName.ToLower().Contains("powerpnt"))
                {
                  pros[i].Kill();
                }
         }
```

**Namespace Required:**

[System.Diagnostics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15t15zda%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

See [Application.Quit() method failing to clear process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197263/application-quit-method-failing-to-clear-process)

There is also the option, of having your apllication check to see if the exe is running, attempt to kill it manually in your finally, but I highly advise against that.