# Open powerpoint with vb.net, leave open and how to release objects when powerpoint is closed?

Tags: vb.net, powerpoint

I have the following code to run a macro in a powerpoint file via VB.NET 2013 Express:

```
        'Start PowerPoint and open the presentation.
        Dim oPP = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application()
        oPP.Visible = MsoTriState.msoTrue
        Dim oPresSet = oPP.Presentations
        Dim oPres = oPresSet.Open(PFile)
        oPP.Run("'Plan.ppt'!UpdatePlan")
        oPres = Nothing
        If Not oPresSet Is Nothing Then
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oPresSet)
            oPresSet = Nothing
        End If
        oPP.Quit()
        If Not oPP Is Nothing Then
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oPP)
            oPP = Nothing
        End If
```

I leave the powerpoint open to view and then close the file via powerpoint. When this code is run the code again, I get the following error with the following line of code:

```
        Dim oPP = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application()
```

Error Message - "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in Plan.exe

Additional information: Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {91493441-5A91-11CF-8700-00AA0060263B} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 800706b5."

Is there any way to release the objects when powerpoint file is closed via powerpoint so that I can re-run the code again without error?

Is there another way to do this so that I don't get these errors?

Been working on this for ages and help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `Set oPP = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application()` instead of `Dim` then `Set oPP = Nothing`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197263/application-quit-method-failing-to-clear-process

Comment: Just tried it but when I use the Set keyword, VB.Net 2013 gets rid of it?

Comment: Sorry i thought it would work that's what is used in visual basic 6.

Comment: Worth a try. Thanks anyway. I'll try anything to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

To release the object run the following sub:

```
''' <summary>
''' This releases the object
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Sub ReleaseObj()
    _pptApp.Quit()
    _pptApp = Nothing
    _pptPre = Nothing
End Sub
```

To get more information check Hans Passant's answer and the links in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25134024/clean-up-excel-interop-objects-with-idisposable).